# how can I remove BIOS boot splash screen on HP Pavilion G series?

Tags: boot, bios, hp-pavilion

In my laptop (HP Pavilion G series) I would like to remove the BIOS logo at boot but I don't know how to. I've tried to flash a new BIOS firmware, but this didn't change the logo. How can I change this logo or remove it? Can someone help me out with a step by step guide ?